# Is there a way to copy and paste text from within a Microsoft Visio document?

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-visio, text-formatting, read-only

A Microsoft Visio document that I was given contains text, but I cannot copy it.  I can only open it in Internet explorer.  If I try to open it in Word, it is just random characters.

Is there a way to copy and paste the text from within the Visio document?

I may add that I don't have the Microsoft Visio program installed on my workstation [I have put in at ticket with our organization to do so, however].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document is in Visio .vdx format then you can. You just need a plain text editor (Notepad++ is ideal). Open the document in Notepad++ and you will see that it is XML format. Do a search for the text you want and copy it within the editor.

If the document is in .vsdx format then you will need to unzip the vsdx file first. Take a backup - do not work on the original document.

If the doument is in .vsd format then this won't work.

Comment: Alas, I had a .vsd format and I had tried Notepad++ -- illegible characters!  However, I did indeed get Microsoft Viso installed on my machine.  IMHO, basic text copying should be included, otherwise the Visio diagram is little more than a bitmap.  [In this particular case there wasn't a true diagram, why the original wasn't done in Word is a question I can't answer].